# How to start using OpenCV and ROS

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Im new in OpenCV and would like to learn using it with ROS fuerte. I am using Ubuntu 12 and 14 and ROS fuerte and Microsoft Kinect. Any good tutorial to start install OpenCV in ROS and start using it with some basic functions to hit the ground? Any help would really appreciate

EDIT:
Do I need to change my CmakeList.txt file ? I found that I you need to include it into my CMakeList.txt (here i mean the CMakeList.txt in my package):

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

target_link_libaries(your_node ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

True?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234018/how-to-start-using-opencv-and-ros/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

Then I would suggest using python first. All you need to do is to import opencv in the top of your python script.

```
import cv2
```

and then do whatever you want. Opencv functions can be called in ROS callbacks. Most interesting thing would be probably converting ROS image messages to opencv format as explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython). This would allow applying image processing algorithms implemented in opencv on the images you get from ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2016-05-10**:
Thanks. Im not familiar with python actually. is any option for using C++?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-05-11**:
Yes, you can use OpenCV with C++. Installing it is done the same way.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-05-11**:
[Here](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages) is an example to publish webcam images using opencv and ros

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2016-05-12**:
Thanks,. I followed the example. when tried to run make I got the following error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv_bridge

I already installed before the cv_bridge package. Should I modify my CmakeList as well?Any help?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-05-12**:
you run make or catkin_make ?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2016-05-12**:
I am using rosbuild. So I run make

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-05-12**:
rosmake + package_name

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2016-05-12**:
No. It does not work. error again

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2016-05-16**:
ok. fix it. work now.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2016-05-18**:
Do you know any launch file to run the node?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2021-04-05**:
Ok. I was the opencv version problem. Ok now